# 'as' test is always true warning in Swift switch statement

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm using `as Int` in a `switch` case to unwrap an optional.  It works, but the compiler gives the warning **'as' test is always true**.  That is a *lie* of course because the `as` only succeeds if the value is not `nil`.

Consider this minimal, verifiable example:

```
var age: Int?

switch age {
case let y as Int:    // warning: 'as' test is always true
    print(y)
case nil:
    print("it is nil")
}
```

Output:

> it is nil

**Questions:** What is Swift thinking here with that warning and is there a better way to unwrap the value without having to use a force unwrap?

Comment: Looks like a bug – and [has been filed here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1703).

Comment: Note that saying `print("\(y)")` is an unnecessary use of string interpolation.

Comment: @matt, yes.  It was a leftover from tearing down a more complex example.  I suppose I could correct it now since no answer directly mentions it.

Comment: Yeah, I deliberately corrected it to `print(y)` in my edit of my formulation. :)

Comment: @matt corrected.  Note that my answer uses string interpolation is a slightly more useful manner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bug, brought on by the `as Int` — because if `y` is not `nil`, it is *certainly* an Int.

The correct syntax in this situation ("is there a better way to unwrap the value without having to use a force unwrap") is:

```
    switch age {
    case let y?:
        print(y)
    case nil:
        print("it is nil")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

The warning ''as' test is always true' also happens with
**"do-try-catch"**, i.e

```
catch let error as Error {
  print("cannot perform the operation - \(error)") //'as' test is always true
}
```

Just remove the typecaste and the warning is gone

```
catch let error {
  print("cannot perform the operation - \(error)")
}
```

This works !

Answer (score 1):

As @Hamish pointed out in the comments, this is a [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1703).

The comments in the bug report suggest a workaround using `.some(let y)` to unwrap the optional.

For example:

```
var age: Int? = 6

switch age {
case .some(let y) where y % 2 == 0:
    print("\(y) is even")
case .some(let y) where y % 2 == 1:
    print("\(y) is odd")
default:
    print("not odd or even, must be nil")
}
```

---

@Hamish comes through again with the suggestion to use the syntactic sugar `case let y?`:

```
var age: Int? = 7

switch age {
case let y? where y % 2 == 0:
    print("\(y) is even")
case let y? where y % 2 == 1:
    print("\(y) is odd")
default:
    print("not odd or even, must be nil")
}
```

Comment: You can also use the syntactic sugar version of the optional pattern `case let y? where y % 2 == 0` :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a switch statement. Switch statement is different from "if let". Switch assumes that you would try to distinguish between different types, not between some type and nil. Just write

```
if let y = age {
    // Not nil
} else {
    // nil
}
```

Comment: It was just a toy (minimal) example to demonstrate the problem.